# Angular - Filter list object to other list

Tags: angular, typescript, list, filter, listobject

I have a custom item:

```js
export class PartsChildInfo {
   name: string;
   materialName: string;
   thickNess: number;
}

export class PartGroupInfo
{
   materialName: string;
   thickNess: number;
}
```

For example, I have a list item `PartsChildInfo`:

```js
list : PartsChildInfo  = [
  { Name = "GA8-0608" , MaterialName = "SS"  , ThickNess = 1 };
  { Name = "05F1-051" , MaterialName = "SUS" , ThickNess = 2 };
  { Name = "2B73-002" , MaterialName = "AL"  , ThickNess = 3 };
  { Name = "01-20155" , MaterialName = "SS"  , ThickNess = 1 };
  { Name = "02MEG099" , MaterialName = "SUS" , ThickNess = 2 }; 
]
```

I want to get the list as below with `MaterialName`, `ThickNess` the same from list :

```js
testChildList : PartGroupInfo = [
  { MaterialName = "SS"  , ThickNess = 1 };
  { MaterialName = "SUS" , ThickNess = 2 };
  { MaterialName = "AL"  , ThickNess = 3 }; 
]
```

I have tried this

```js
testChildList : PartGroupInfo[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   let targeti = list[i];
   for (let j = 0; j < this.testChildList.length; j++) {
      let targetj = this.testChildList[j];
      if (targeti.materialName != targetj.materialName && targeti.thickNess != targetj.thickNess) {
        let item = new PartGroupInfo();
        item.materialName = targeti.materialName;
        item.thickNess = targeti.thickNess;
        this.testChildList.push(item);
       }
    }
 }
```

but the returned list is null. How should I fix it?

Comment: What is `data[j]`?

Comment: @YongShun i'm sr, i edited in post but still return null list

Comment: I guess `this.testChildList.push(item);` should be `testChildList.push(item);`

Comment: @N.F. thanks , but it still return null list

Comment: Which variable are you going to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use `.forEach` to iterate the `list` array, check the item is existed in `testChildList` via `index`. Push the `item` to `testChildList` when index is -1 (no existed).

```js
this.list.forEach((item) => {
  var i = this.testChildList.findIndex(
    (x) =>
      x.materialName == item.materialName && x.thickNess == item.thickNess
  );

  if (i == -1)
    this.testChildList.push({
      materialName: item.materialName,
      thickNess: item.thickNess,
    });
});
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-raqrh9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: at the first "testChildList"  is empty list . and i want filter the "list " to get the element with both materialName and thickNess . can you watch it for me ?

Comment: Okay, let me summarize your requirement, you want to get  materialName and thickNess from `list ` and it is distinct?

Comment: yesss, it right

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarify the requirements and I had updated my answer.

Comment: I followed and it worked. thank you very much. I will put it as the answer !